# Bootstrap 4 - how to make text be in relative position to each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="border rounded-lg" style="height:500px;">
        <div class="ml-2 mt-2">
            <h1 class="display-3">@Model.Name</h1>
            <!-- Image and pay box -->
            <div class="mt-4 container">
                <img src="~/Resources/default.jpg" class="" style="height:300px;" />
                <div class="d-inline align-top float-right border rounded-lg" style="height:250px;width:250px;">
                    @if (!Model.OnSale)
                    {
                        <h3 class="mt-2 text-nowrap text-center text-warning">@Model.Price</h3>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2 text-center">
                                <div class="text-secondary font-italic" style="text-align:center;"><s>@Model.PriceBeforeDiscount</s></div>
                                <div class="mt-2 text-nowrap text-warning">@Model.Price</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <button class="btn btn-success text-white text-center font-weight-bold w-100 mt-3">
                        BUY NOW
                    </button>
```

given a model, it looks like [image: this:]
I want to center both price texts (the ones on the right), but for some reason, it will refuse to use "text-center", any ideas on how I can solve this? (the @ sign is just from Razor syntax, it's the variables it displays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text prices are center aligned in your code but they're being constrained by the column width

`col-2` should be `col-12`_ thus:

```
@if (!Model.OnSale)
{
    <h3 class="mt-2 text-nowrap text-center text-warning">@Model.Price</h3>
}
else
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <div class="text-secondary font-italic"><s>@Model.PriceBeforeDiscount</s></div>
            <div class="mt-2 text-nowrap text-warning">@Model.Price</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I can't recreate the code here but have tested it locally and `col-12` appears to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center"></div>`

This should work